# React useEffect to save textarea text

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am trying to make a memo pad where a user can write in a textarea and save it.
When the page opens, I want the same text to remain in the textarea.

I don't want to use the `onChange` event because it gets rendered with every input
So I am trying to use `onSubmit` and `useEffect`.

I am new to react and trying to understand hooks. But after reading all the documents I am still lost.

I am using Ionic framework and below is my code,

```
<IonCard>
       <form className="memo" onSubmit={handleSubmit(text)}>
             <IonItemDivider><IonLabel>관리자용 메모판</IonLabel></IonItemDivider>          
             <IonItem>
                  <IonTextarea id="memoTextarea" rows={28} value={text} name="memoTextarea" ref={register({})} ></IonTextarea>
             </IonItem>
             <IonButton type="submit" fill="solid">저장</IonButton>
       </form>
</IonCard>
```

Can anybody help me, how will I implement the `useEffect` code ?

```
useEffect(()=>{
      

}, []);
```

What do I put inside `handleSubmit()`?

Comment: You want to store the value of textarea which means you need to store the value in a state variable. You might need to use `onChange` to track the value.

Comment: @DarshnaRekha yeah I know that onChange will make things simpler but validation will trigger on the change event with each input, and lead to multiple re-renders. So I think it will have a significant impact on performance. So I want to make the memo without onChange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[react-hook-form](/questions/tagged/react-hook-form) uses uncontrolled components by default. *Uncontrolled* means you don't have to control the state yourself, the components handle it for you (in this case `IonTextarea`). It also means that your parent component doesn't re-render because it doesn't have to reflect the changes from the dependency state since it doesn't have any.

You can make sure the component is uncontrollable by *not* initializing the value in the input component. You can confirm that your component doesn't re-render by logging in the render method.

```js
<IonTextarea
  id="memoTextarea"
  rows={28}
  // comment the following line will make the component uncontrollable
  // and your component never re-renders when you type
  // value={text}
  name="memoTextarea"
  ref={r => register(r)}
></IonTextarea>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64135168/react-useeffect-to-save-textarea-text]